# Adding Object files to FreeBSD Kernel Crypto Module

Tags: encryption, makefile, kernel, freebsd, kernel-module

I added a new cipher to FreeBSD kernel, but i want to link some object files to my cipher. I am having difficulty figuring out how to link those object files.

The .c files of my cipher are located in /usr/src/sys/crypto/mycipher

and the make file for the crypto module looks located in /usr/src/sys/modules/crypto looks like this:

$FreeBSD: release/9.2.0/sys/modules/crypto/Makefile 212496 2010-09-12 16:28:26Z ivoras $

.PATH:  ${.CURDIR}/../../opencrypto
.PATH:  ${.CURDIR}/../../crypto
.PATH:  ${.CURDIR}/../../crypto/blowfish
.PATH:  ${.CURDIR}/../../crypto/des
.PATH:  ${.CURDIR}/../../crypto/rijndael
.PATH:  ${.CURDIR}/../../crypto/sha2
.PATH:  ${.CURDIR}/../../crypto/camellia
**.PATH:   ${.CURDIR}/../../crypto/mycipher**

KMOD    = crypto
SRCS    = crypto.c cryptodev_if.c
SRCS    += criov.c cryptosoft.c xform.c
SRCS    += cast.c deflate.c rmd160.c rijndael-alg-fst.c rijndael-api.c
SRCS    += skipjack.c bf_enc.c bf_ecb.c bf_skey.c
SRCS    += des_ecb.c des_enc.c des_setkey.c
SRCS    += sha1.c sha2.c
SRCS    += opt_param.h cryptodev_if.h bus_if.h device_if.h
SRCS    += opt_ddb.h opt_kdtrace.h
SRCS    += camellia.c camellia-api.c
**SRCS += mycipher.c**
.include <bsd.kmod.mk>

I want to link mycipher.c with abc.o , how can i do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer would be this:

SRCS += abc.c

But since it's a pretty obvious answer, I suspect I'm missing something in your question.  Do I?

Comment: Yeah, i'm sorry if it wasn't very clear. I don't have the source file for abc i only have the object file abc.o and i want to link it with mycipher.c because mycipher.c is using some functions in abc.o